# E F# G# Am Chord Progression

Tags: chord-progressions

So I have a chord progression in the key of G like

E7 D7/F# E7/G# Am

I know there's an element of tonicization here but explain the F# in between please? What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is simply an A minor progression. The A Melodic Minor scale is:

> A B C D E F# G# A

So, seeing a progression of:

> E  G# B D - E7
>
> F# A  C D - D7/F#
>
> G# B  D E - E7/G#
>
> A  C  E A - Am

or whatever the exact voicings may be, is very understandable and common. Whether or not the piece modulated from G Major to A Minor, I could not say.

Comment: Don't think so though. Seeing as secondary dominants apply here, it is an A major progression:

A B C# D E F# G#

I do know that the norm is, if your target is Am, you can choose either of these:

E to Am
E7 to Am
E/G# to Am
E7/G# to Am

Just don't get the theory why the F# in between.

Comment: @tjvg1991 I am not sure why you are saying that it is an A Major progression when the defining note of the A Major triad is missing (C#) and the A Major chord is missing. Either way, the F# is the 6th degree of the A Melodic Minor scale, as noted here: https://www.basicmusictheory.com/a-melodic-minor-scale

Answer (score 1):

If this is in the Key of G the D7 chord is the V (fifth) chord.
D7/F# means that you are playing F# in the bass of the D7 chord. 
F# is the 3rd of the chord, and the 7th in the key of G (i.e. it is diatonic to the key).
hope that helps.

Comment: I get that. Why I don't get is why the F# when transitioning from E to Am.

Comment: There are two things going on here. The chords and the bass line. The chords are E7 D7 E7 Am. The bass line is just an ascending line - E F# G# A. The composer could have just given the chords but wanted to specify the ascending bass line so it is given with the chords. The F# is the 3rd of the D7 chord and the composer wants that chord played with the 3rd in the base to get the ascending bass line. This will give a very different feel than having all roots in the bass. Hope that helps.